# differences between chkconfig vs insserv?

Tags: services

I know `chkconfig` we are not using currently to manager services in Ubuntu but even its a old tool, its a good tool. but recently I've gone through `insserv` .

All I want to know is what are the main difference between `insserv` and `chkconfig` tools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[chkconfig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chkconfig.8.html) is just a [wrapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) and [insserv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_wrapper) is the actual command.

From the man page of chkconfig:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> chkconfig  is  used  to manipulate the runlevel links at boot time (see init.d(7)). **It  can  be  thought  of  as  a  frontend  to  insserv(8)**. Chkconfig  can  run  in six different modes: terse list mode, set mode, edit mode, list mode, add mode and delete mode. The  last  three  modes were added for compatiblity reasons.

Comment: so can we maintain run levels with insserv ?

Comment: insserv reads the scripts itself and those have the run levels on where to start

Comment: oh our man pages have a few difference along release: this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/insserv.8.html has a bit about run levels other man page have not